# Can I call a method from the same method?

Tags: php, class, laravel-5.1, static-methods

I'm in a situation where I need to call the same method if any exception is thrown to ensure I'm not duplicating any code. However, it's not working as I thought. Here's the relevant code:

```
public static function getFolderObject($folder_id)
    {
        $client = new Client('https://api.box.com/{version}/folders', [
            'version' => '2.0',
            'request.options' => [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . self::getAccessToken(),
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $request = $client->get($folder_id);

        try {
            $response = $request->send();
            $result = $response->json();

            $files = $result['item_collection']['entries'];
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            $result = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();

            if ($result === 401) {
                self::regenerateAccessToken();
                self::getFolderObject();
            }
        }

        return count($files) ? $files : false;
    }
```

As you can see I'm calling the method from the method method under the `if` condition `self::getFolderObject();` to prevent duplicate code again in under the `if` statement from beginning of the method. However, if I duplicate the code it works as expected. Is there any solution to achieve what I want?

Comment: It looks like you're not passing in the `$folder_id` variable when you call the method again. You also need to `return` the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to return the value and assign the folder_id:

```
public static function getFolderObject($folder_id)
    {
        $client = new Client('https://api.box.com/{version}/folders', [
            'version' => '2.0',
            'request.options' => [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . self::getAccessToken(),
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $request = $client->get($folder_id);

        try {
            $response = $request->send();
            $result = $response->json();

            $files = $result['item_collection']['entries'];
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            $result = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();

            if ($result === 401) {
                self::regenerateAccessToken();
                return self::getFolderObject($folder_id);
            }
        }

        return count($files) ? $files : false;
    }
```